# About the use of dotted hostname with avahi

Tags: avahi, hostname

I recently discovered avahi. It help you when you when to resolve hostname for the local network. But in my situation I've got a issue.

I decided to host a machine called `a.alpha` and a another called `b.alpha`.
In a near future I will also use some machine called `a.beta` and `b.beta`.
My problem is that from `a.alpha` I can resolve `a.alpha.local` hostname, but currently I can't resolve `a.alpha.local` from `b.alpha`.

So when I will decide to use the `.beta` extension I will have some issues.

Is it normal that the machine "a.alpha" doesn't expos the entire hostname to mdns ?

I know i can change the naming method (saying use a-alpha instead of `a.alpha`). But I like it this way.

So the question is:
Is it possible to use dotted name in the `/etc/hostname` and to resolve it using avahi?

Answer (score 1):

see https://serverfault.com/questions/229331/linitation-in-linux-hostname-about-dot